# get uploaded file size in bytes in php

Tags: php

I am uploading a file which is an image. I want to get the size of that image every time in bytes only using PHP. I had done this by far

```
$name=$_FILES['image']['name'];
if($name!=null)
{
    $tmpDest=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $size=$_FILES['image']['size'];
    $perDestination="main/$name";
    $result=move_uploaded_file($tmpDest,$perDestination);
    echo $size;
}
```

Comment: And what is not working?

Comment: dont know how to get filesize in bytes every time

Comment: That's exactly what this is `$_FILES['image']['size'];`.  That's why I ask _what is the problem_?

Comment: I want to know what does it return. whether it returns file size in kbs, mbs

Comment: Easy enough http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: thanks @AbraCadaver .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code is right, the below line will give you the size in bytes:

```
size=$_FILES['image']['size'];
```

You can also get the file size after the file has been uploaded this way:

```
echo filesize($perDestination) . ' bytes';
```

This option will also give you the file size in bytes

Comment: does the uploaded file size always comes in bytes

Answer (score 2):

You can check like this

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['file']) {
    if($_FILES['file']['size'] > 10485760) { //10 MB (size is also in bytes)
        // File too big
    } else {
        // File within size restrictions
    }
}
```

check this out 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: I want to get the size of that image every time in bytes as it should convert that size into bytes automatically.

Comment: it always gives the size is bytes so what's the problem